# Need to handle special characters in URL

Tags: java, xml

My input html is

```
<p>
<span>first
</span>
<a href="http://tools.google.com/dlpage/cloudconnect#utm_campaign=launch&utm_source=en-na-us-gdb-GCC-Appsperience_02242011&utm_medium=blog"><span>Google Cloud Connect for Microsoft Office</span></a>
</p>
```

I am using xslt1.0 to convert the html to xml..my output xml is

```
<Relationship Id="rId12700703801" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/hyperlink" Target="http://tools.google.com/dlpage/cloudconnect#utm_campaign=launch&utm_source=en-na-us-gdb-GCC-Appsperience_02242011&utm_medium=blog" TargetMode="External"/></Relationships>
```

with error "XML Parsing Error: not well-formed" in the location =(after launch&utm_source) in target attribute..

I want to escape the special characters present in url through xslt and make the xml.
Please help me. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

are you generating the input html? if so you can use URLEncoder.encode to properly encode the string so the transformer doesn't complain about the syntax.

If this is just a random html page, and you have no control over it, then you probably need to use some html parser, such as tagsoup, et. al, to pre-correct it as most html files are not properly formatted.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT expects XML as input, not HTML. You need to turn your HTML into XML if you want to transform it with XSLT.

I think it might be possible to do it with [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: i did all this..but how to truncate the special characters in html href attribute to match with xml..

Comment: @vignesh: Did you use the `fix-uri` option of HTML Tidy?

Comment: There is no need for that. `&` character must be escape as entity reference `&amp;`, and that's what Tidy correctly does.

Comment: @Alejandro: Yeah, but vignesh said "i did all this". I'm not sure what that's supposed to mean.